# What should we do to fetch mutiple $_GET values

Tags: php, forms, loops, get

If the output of a get(method) form is like this:

```
test.php?test=hi&test=how&test=why&test=where
```

how can we fetch all these values at once through a loop or any other php code.

Comment: Have you read even a basic tutorial on PHP?

Comment: RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: `var_export($_GET)` to see the structur of the `$_GET` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the parsing yourself in that case:

```
$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$items = array();

foreach (explode('&', $qs) as $pair) {
    $args = explode('=', $pair, 2);

    if (!isset($args[1])) {
        $args[1] = '';
    }

    $items[$args[0]][] = $args[1];
}
```

This would be a whole lot simpler if you could use this query string:

```
test.php?test[]=hi&test[]=how&test[]=why&test[]=where
```

In that case, you can simply use `$_GET` directly.

Comment: @Mega nvm, there was a mistake in my answer. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the example shown, only a single value for `$_GET['test']` will ever be shown. That is because parameter names must be unique.  If however you wanted an array of `test` values you could use a URI like this:

```
test.php?test[]=hi&test[]=how&test[]=why&test[]=where
```

Note the array notation `[]` in `test[]`.

This will build an array of "test" such that `$_GET['test'])` would store an array of values like this:

```
Array(
    0 => 'hi',
    1 => 'how',
    2 => 'why',
    3 => 'where'
)
```

Comment: how will I catch it now in foreach or in any other loop.

Comment: @MegaBasil You want me to tell you how to write a foreach loop?

Comment: and my code is like this
    $y = $_GET['test'];
    if(isset($_GET['allowed'])) 
    {
    foreach($y as $country){
    mysql_query("UPDATE geocity SET isAllowed= 1  WHERE `country`   ='mysql_real_escape_string($country)'  ");
    }}
    else {
    foreach($y as $country){
    mysql_query("UPDATE geocity SET isAllowed=0  WHERE `country` ='mysql_real_escape_string($country)'  ");
    } }

Comment: For the record, I think updating a database based on GET is a REALLY bad idea.  You could have people modifying database records in different ways just by navigating forward and back in their browser.  They could end up overwriting data they just tried to update for example.  You should really use POST for any functionality that is going to change you database (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

Comment: thanks for telling I'll use the POST But the problem will remain the same.

Comment: Like I said, you are only going to get a single string value for `test` using the parameter string you show in the original question.  If you use array notation the value `$_GET['test']` will be an array, which should work with the code you show.

Comment: And how can I make that array. Please explain your answer

Comment: @MegaBasil As I mentioned in my answer above the parameters in the query string (whether GET or POST) should be `test[]` instead of `test` (if using a form, make this the name value for the fields). PHP will automatically take all parameters named as `*[]` and populate them as an array into `$_GET['*']`

Comment: in the form i change my input name from "test" to "test[]" but in url it just incode it.